# General recursion to tail-recursion

Tags: recursion, tail-recursion, lambda-calculus

Is it theoretically possible to transform *every* kind of general-recursion into tail-recursion? Are they equivalent for example from a lambda-calculus point of view? That's a debate between me and an acquaintance.

My view is that it's not possible everytime. For example if you have a function which calls itself recursively twice or three times, then you can't make all the recursive calls into tail-calls, right? Or is there always a way to reduce the number of recursive calls to one single recursive call?

Comment: You might want to put this on the Programmers stack exchange // http://programmers.stackexchange.com/

Answer (score 0):

No. If you cannot rewrite your algorithm to have only tail calls, like in tree traversal, at least one call will not be in tail position.

Some may say loop + explicit stack is iterative, but IMO it's still recursion and a tree traversal will grow the stack just as general recursion.